# How to split French date and time in Java

Tags: java, datetime, french

Trying to split the date and time which comes in the French style like the example below:

23 sept. 2021 à 13:30:57

And the final result should be the example below:

23-09-2021 and 13:30:57

The issue comes because of the << à >> when trying to get the time.
I've tried with the different way such as DateTimeFormatter, DateFormat etc...

Could you please help?
thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just ignore that and parse `23 sept. 2021 13:30:57`?

Comment: @m0skit0 thanks for the reply. The values come with that format, how to ignore them? could you please provide some examples?
Thanks

Comment: You can just replace ' à ' with a space  then parse it.

Answer (score 5):

## Localization

The *java.time* classes can automatically [localize](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization). So let them parse your localized input. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

This approach works because your input uses the format defined by the [*Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) used by default in modern Java.

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "23 sept. 2021 à 13:30:57" , 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM )
    .withLocale( Locale.FRANCE )
) 
.toString()
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/yeGUYp).

> 2021-09-23T13:30:57